# How to calculate maximum and minimum orbital speed from orbital elements?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

Given the following orbital elements, how should I calculate the minimum and maximum speed of the satellite?

> Mean Orbital Altitude: $950$ km
> Inclinination: $23.1$ deg
> Eccentricity: $0.1$
> Right ascension of the ascending node: $94$ deg
> Satellite mass: $150$ kg

I'm thinking about using Vis-Viva equation, but I'm not sure how to calculate the semimajor axis and the distance between the satellite and Earth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already on the right track with the
vis-viva equation.
For using it you need to extract some simple facts
from the given orbital elements of the ellipse.

In an elliptic orbit the mean radius is the semi-major axis $a$.
Therefore, from

> Mean Orbital Altitude: $950$ km

you get the mean radius (i.e. the semi-major axis $a$)
by adding the mean altitude to the radius of the earth
($6370\text{ km}$).
$$a = 6370\text{ km} + 950\text{ km}$$

And from

> Eccentricity: $0.1$

and the definition of the eccentricity $\epsilon$ you can calculate
the minimum and maximum radius of the ellipse:
$$r_\text{min}=a(1-\epsilon)$$
$$r_\text{max}=a(1+\epsilon)$$

Comment: thanks! But do I need the right ascension angle and the inclination at all?

Comment: @ArnoldSchwarzenegger No, you don't need these. They are specifying how the orbit is tilted relative to the equator.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to calculate the argument of periapsis (W) and the true anomaly (TA) from the orbital elements given above?

Comment: @No, these are independent from the given 4 orbital elements